# jquery with lodash $.map

Tags: jquery, lodash

I want to use `lodash` in my code.

I used `jQuery` but I want to replace with `lodash`-

My jQuery Code :

```
$scope.annotations = $scope.dashboard.annotations.list;
var indexes = $.map($scope.annotations, function(obj, index) {
    if(obj.name === annotation) {
        return index;
    }
});
var firstIndex = indexes[0];
$scope.annotations.splice(firstIndex, 1);
```

I am find the index value of matched object.
What to replace in place of `$.map` I tried `_.map` and `_.filter` not getting exact result.

Comment: Seems to me like Angular scope element annotations and underscore map method. You usually do not mix jQuery with Angular as it is not considered a good practice. In any case it seems unclear what you want to archive. Maybe some input data, with what you expect and what you get, can remedy this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct?

My Code :

```
  $scope.annotations = $scope.dashboard.annotations.list;
  var index = _.findIndex($scope.annotations, function(obj) {
    return obj.name === annotation;
  });
  $scope.annotations.splice(index, 1);
```

This is working fine.. Just want to know logic wise its correct or not.